# Find the maximum value of $\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{1+a^2+b^2}$

Tags: inequality, maxima-minima

Given $a,b,c$ are positive satisfy $ab+bc+ca\ge3$. FInd the maximum value of $$\frac{1}{1+a^2+b^2}+\frac{1}{1+b^2+c^2}+\frac{1}{1+c^2+a^2}$$

---

By C-S $(a^2+b^2+1)(1+1+c^2)\geq (a+b+c)^2$

$\Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{a^2+b^2+1}\leq \frac{2+c^2}{(a+b+c)^2}$

$\frac{1}{a^2+b^2+1}+\frac{1}{b^2+c^2+1}+\frac{1}{c  ^2+a^2+1}\leq \frac{6+a^2+b^2+c^2}{(a+b+c)^2}$

$\Leftrightarrow ab+bc+ca \geq 3\Leftrightarrow (a+b+c)^2 \geq 6+a^2+b^2+c^2$

Hence Max=1. **Right** or **Wrong**. If wrong can fix for me ?

Comment: If you take $a=b=c=1$, you see that the value $1$ is reached. So yes, it is the maximum.

Comment: @Word Shallow   I think your solution is true.